# Configuring Mule Microsoft Power BI connector using OAUTH

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft Power BI using the Mule Power BI connector but the connector configuration is very confusing with respect to OAuth. Has anyone successfully connected to Power BI with Mule? Here is my config:

```
    <power-bi-rest:config name="Power_Bi_Rest_Connector_Config" doc:name="Power Bi Rest Connector Config" doc:id="d9dbee0f-50fe-46ca-977e-2b3c6ce1ff3b" >
        <power-bi-rest:oauth2-authorization-code-connection >
            <power-bi-rest:oauth-authorization-code consumerKey="xxx" consumerSecret="yyy" authorizationUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/69f2560d-6d2a-4768-989e-d35ed85aeab2/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" accessTokenUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/69f2560d-6d2a-4768-989e-d35ed85aeab2/oauth2/v2.0/token" scopes="api://96eb9d1c-6dfb-4acf-9950-d4af04038693/Mule"/>
            <power-bi-rest:oauth-callback-config listenerConfig="HTTP_Listener_config" callbackPath="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient" authorizePath="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient" />
        </power-bi-rest:oauth2-authorization-code-connection>
    </power-bi-rest:config>
```

[image]

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Paste the XML of the configuration in the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have not specifically used Power BI but I can tell the what the issue probably is.
The `oAUthCallbackConfig` is where you will need to make the changes.

1. External Callback URL: While configuring the OAuth credentials in your MS account, you must have provided a callback URL that should be pointing to your Mule application. You need to put that URL here.
2. Callback Path: Here you need to mention where the Mule App should be expecting to get the call back with the authorization code. For example of you have configured external path as `https://localhost:8082/oauth/callback`this parameter could be `oauth/callback`. (Note that you will need to consider the base path that you may have configured in the http listener)
3. Authorize path: This should not be a URL pointing to a Microsoft api, but it is the path that you will use to hit you mule app to start the oAuth dance. You can put something like `/oauth/authorize`. Then when you try `https://localhost:8082/oauth/authorize` the mule app will trigger the oAuth dance and will redirect you to the login screen of everything else is setup correctly.